# How to re-request BLUETOOTH_SCAN and BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permissions for Android 12 after a user denial?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-bluetooth

I have a problem re-requesting the permissions required to scan and connect to bluetooth devices when targeting SDK 31 (Android 12).

I call this method inside my main activity's `onCreate()`:

```
public void requestBluetoothPermissions() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {

        if ((this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            || (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

            Log.w(getClass().getName(), "requestBluetoothPermissions() BLUETOOTH_SCAN AND BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permissions needed => requesting them...");

            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
            }, MyActivity.REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSIONS);

        }
    }
}
```

It's works fine the first time it is called i.e. an Android pop-up is displayed to the user, prompting him to grant the permissions.

But if he refuses to grant the permissions, next time `onCreate()` is called, the pop-up will not be displayed, which means the user remains unable to grant the permissions.

Any idea why and how to fix this ?

Comment: `||` doesn't mean "AND".

Comment: How do you handle the result of permission?

Comment: @MartinZeitler I know ! I need both permissions to be granted

Comment: @Kozmotronik If permissions are granted, I start scanning for Bluetooth devices

Comment: @matdev I mean how do you handle the **user denial**? Well, you start a scan if the permission is granted, but what do you do if the permission is not granted? How do you handle the rejection? Because as a developer, you're supposed to inform the user either using a alert dialogue or toast message about what features will not be available if he/she denies the permission. A dialog might be better since you can redirect the user to the permission settings of your application. See [Androiddenial handling guide](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting#handle-denial)

Comment: I handle user denial with a snackbar message prompting user to enter the app permission settings and grant the permissions. But that's not ideal, because user may not understand what he has to do. I'd rather re-display the OS pop-up prompting user to grant the permissions. But apparently the OS does not allow this...

Comment: I see. Yes unfortunately the OS pop-up is not prompting anymore even the user doesn't select *Don't show again* option. Although Google encourages the developers to check `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` to explain why the app needs this permission it didn't work on API 31 either. So I had to show a dialog with app settings option every time the user hits the part where the bluetooth permissions are needed.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, this could be an answer @Kozmotronik Actually I've implemented a similar solution using the snackbar: If `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()` returns true, I display snackbar allowing user to grant the permissions from the app settings. If it returns false, I request the permissions using `requestPermissions()`

Comment: One more thing to mention: Before `onrequestpermissionsresult` is being deprecated, I was using `startActivityForResult` to request permission. The `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` was returning true when it should with the deprecated API. But after the deprecation I migrated to `ActivityResultLauncher` API. With the `ActivityResultLauncher`, `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale`  never returned true. That's why I had to go with the logic what I've mentioned before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears Android 12 blocks requesting the same permission after user denied it once only.

Therefore, I ended up using `ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN)` to determine wether the permission can be requested or not, in which case a snackbar message is displayed explaining why is the permission needed, with a button opening the app settings where permission can be granted.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
public void requestBluetoothPermissions() {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {

        if ((this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
            || (this.checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {

            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(getActivity(),
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN)) {

                 // display permission rationale in snackbar message
            } else {
                Log.w(getClass().getName(), "requestBluetoothPermissions() BLUETOOTH_SCAN AND BLUETOOTH_CONNECT permissions needed => requesting them...");

                this.requestPermissions(new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                    }, MyActivity.REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSIONS);
            }
        }
    }
}
```